# Anonymous Inner Class Issue in Javassist generated class

Tags: java, javassist

I am using Javassist to generate some classes at runtime and when I make anonymous inner classes in these classes they crash upon trying to instantiate an enclosing object (as far as I can tell)

I have tried to implement the simplest version of what I am trying to do.

I define 3 classes as follows:

```
public class A {

    public int method() {
        return 1;
    }
}

public class B extends A {

}

public class C extends A {
    public int method() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

What I want to do now is use javassist (or something else I guess) to (at runtime) generate a class that has all of the functionality of C but that extends B instead of A, to me this seems like a thing that would be fine, since B extends A. Currently I am doing this as follows:

```
ClassPool cp = ClassPool.getDefault();
CtClass cc = cp.get(C.class.getName());

cc.setName("newName");
cc.setSuperclass(cp.get(B.class.getName()));

B b = (B) cc.toClass().newInstance();

b.method();
```

The above code works fine when I call method(), but If I instantiate an anonymous inner class in C's method() like this:

```
public class C extends A {
    public int method() {
        try {
            return new Callable<Integer>() {

                @Override
                public Integer call() throws Exception {
                    return 5;
                }

            }.call();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

when I call `method()` I get `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: C$1.<init>(LnewName;)` error.

Comment: I don't know JavaAssist but it sounds like it isn't creating the anonymous inner class. Why do you need to do this anyway? It sounds like a symptom of flawed object inheritance design.

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing something pretty silly, I accept that I might have to do it differently, but figured I might ask

Answer (score 2):

While I would love for someone to tell me differently I think this may not be possible with Javassist, I found the following line in section 4.7 of the Javassist tutorial:

"Inner classes or anonymous classes are not supported."

So I guess I should look into other runtime class generation libraries

Comment: Inner classes are supported, but only static ones

Comment: And does anyone know if there is an alternative to work with non-static inner classes?

Answer (score 2):

Javassist doesn't support non-static inner classes.
See javadoc for method [`CtClass.makeNestedClass(String nestedClassName,boolean isStatic)`](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/html/javassist/CtClass.html#makeNestedClass).
Your problem can't be resolved unless you move to top-level your anon inner class.

Comment: I tried the makenestedclass API it added the Class in CtClass object but when i converted the CtClass object to a class object the inner class is not there. As far as i read there will be problem in byte code conversion of  innerclass 

see this https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist/issues/6